# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/jena/fuseki/cmd/FusekiCmd : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, jena, semantic-web, fuseki, apache-jena

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/jena/fuseki/cmd/FusekiCmd : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd. Program will exit
```

When I try to run apache-jena-fuseki-2.0 above error occurs. How can I fix this?

Comment: The code has be compiled with a higher version of Java then it is been run on (ie compiled using Java 7 and run with Java 6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apache-jena-fuseki-2.0 requires Java JDK 1.7 or above. By upgrading the Java version above issue can be fixed. [Refer](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-756)

## update

The code has be compiled with a higher version of Java then it is been run on (ie compiled using Java 8 and run with Java 7)